# Почему ломается на больших числах?

Tags: массивы, c

```
//******************Генератор слов длинной word_module******************

 int X = word_module;
 int SIZE = pow(2., X);
 int COMMON_SIZE = SIZE * X;

 int * * array_by_x = (int * * ) malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
     array_by_x[i] = (int * ) malloc(X * sizeof(int));
 }

 // Генератор последовательности 000..0 000..1 ... 111..1
 for (int i = 0, j, cur_i; i < SIZE; ++i) {
     for (j = X - 1, cur_i = i; j >= 0; --j) {
         if (cur_i) {
             array_by_x[i][j] = cur_i & 1; // заталкиваем последний бит числа i в массив
             cur_i >>= 1; // переходим к следующему биту числа i
         } else {
             array_by_x[i][j] = 0;
         }
     }
 }

 /*for(int i = 0, j; i < SIZE; ++i)
            {
    for(j = 0; j < X; ++j)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d", array_by_x[i][j]);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, " ");
 }*/

 int * array_common = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * (COMMON_SIZE));

 for (int i = 0, ii = 0, j; i < SIZE; ++i) {
     for (j = 0; j < X; ++j, ++ii) {
         array_common[ii] = array_by_x[i][j];
     }
 }

 /*fprintf(stdout, "\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < pow(2.,X)*X; ++i)
            {
                printf("%d \n", array_common[i]);

            }*/
```

На примере. Пусть X=3. Имеем 000 001 010 ... 111. Всё это в итого должно записаться в массив такс 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 ... 1 1 1. Но на больших числах он этого не делает. Почему ?

Comment: @Руслан Лутфуллин, **на больших** - это каких? И **как именно** программа не делает то, что ожидается?

Наиболее вероятная причина - переполнение int. Если он 32-разрядный, то очевидно, что при word_module=30 уже переполнится COMMON_SIZE.

Вторая причина - malloc может не выделить *много* памяти. Желательно проверять, не возвращает ли она NULL.

Вряд ли кто-то будет разбираться с вашим кодом при столь лаконичном описании проблемы.

Comment: Но некоторые замечания все же есть:

* Слишком сложные манипуляции с массивами и значениями разрядов. Любое число и так в памяти в двоичном коде, достаточно перебора в цикле всех значений от 0 до 2^N-1 и поразрядных операций, чтобы получить двоичное представление.

* В первом malloc ошибка, должно быть malloc(SIZE * sizeof **(int *)** )

* Вместо pow(2.,X) используйте (1<<X).